# Assigning a value to a field depending on values in other fields in MySQL

Tags: mysql, relationship

I have 2 MySQL tables, one for stories and one for chapters, I have the fields `created_at` and `main_story` in the chapters table, I also have `last_chapter_date` and `story_name` in the stories table, I want the stories table to check for the latest row created in the chapters table and assign it's `created_at` value to the `last_chapter_date` field.

How do I do that?

**I am sorry if my question isn't so clear, but I don't really know how to make it more clear, plus the title doesn't really explain it so well, sorry.
If you need any other information I will try my best.**

**Edited to provide this link for better visual explaination:**
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IfQ60Ct1mQMzgvY-UqeLdYm1D7dSTCPh

Comment: You can do it more clearer by showing us your data and how the output should look like.

Answer (score 0):

```
stories
story_id | last_chapter_date | story_name

chapter
story_id | created_at | main_story
```

I hope you have the foreign key in the chapter table as shown above, if not then its better to create the table this way and later on you can query for the latest chapter by using this query

```
SELECT * FROM chapter c WHERE c.story_id = <your story_id> ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I am just a beginner in mysql, can you tell me what is that `c` after the table name?

Comment: it is called aliases in the database which is used to shorten the SQL queries for example lets say you need to select all fields from chapter table then instead of using this 

select chapter.story_id, chapter.created_at, chapter.main_story from chapter; 

you can write

select c.story_id, c.created_at, c.main_story from chapter c; 

here c will represent the chapter table

Comment: so I query for the latest chapter then, how do I assign it to the `last_chapter_date` in the stories table? forgive my stupid questions, I am just still learning